# How to know the number of active/alive threads in SyncTaskExecutor?

Tags: spring, executor

ThreadPoolTaskExecutor has getActiveCount() method, but SynctaskExecutor has nothing.
How do i know if any thread in running/active/alive in the thread pool in case of SyncTaskExecutor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no thread pool in `SyncTaskExecutor`. Look at the [implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/task/SyncTaskExecutor.java). This executor doesn't run your task on thread pool. It runs task on calling thread - the thread from which you've called `SyncTaskExecutor`. So actually it's same as you would run your task directly without `SyncTaskExecutor`, however it's useful in tests - you can use this implementation and you'll have blocking code, so you won't have to wait for complete of asynchronous invocation.